# Does Rust automatically implement clone when dereference?

Tags: rust

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Copy for Point {}

impl Clone for Point {
    fn clone(&self) -> Point {
        *self
    }
}
```

When I only implement `Copy`, Rust tells me I need to implement `Clone`. When I only implement `Clone`, Rust tells me `Point` can be moved.

My question is, I have never implemented anything, This code is a bit like a circular dependency, but it works? Why?

Comment: It isn't a circular dependency, but it may indeed be a bit surprising. Consider enabling [this Clippy lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/stable/index.html#expl_impl_clone_on_copy).

Comment: Rust NEVER automatically clone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: `Copy` requires `Clone` for convenience and `Clone` on a `Copy` type is usually implemented using a copy.

---

The Rust compiler will routinely have to do bit-wise copy of your data. But there are two cases:

- If the type does *not* implement `Copy`, the original instance isn't usable anymore, your data has *moved*.
- If the type does implement `Copy`, the compiler knows that it's perfectly safe to continue using the original instance together with the new instance.

The `Copy` trait does not change the fact that the compiler will only automatically do bit-wise copies: It is a marker trait with no methods. Its job is only to tell the compiler “it's OK to continue using this after a bit-wise copy”.

The `Clone` trait isn't that special: It's a regular trait with a method that can do whatever you want it to do. The compiler never uses the `Clone` trait automatically and doesn't care about what it actually does. However it is clearly intended to create a *clone* of an instance, so it is perfectly normal to:

- expect `Copy` types to implement `Clone`. After all, `Copy` is a more strict version of `Clone`. This is why `Copy: Clone` and you have to implement `Clone` on a `Copy` type.
- expect `Clone` on a `Copy` type to be dumb and only perform a bit-wise copy. You wouldn't want two different semantics here, that would be very confusing. This is why `clone` is implemented with a simple `*self` in your example: This dereferences `self`, which causes a bit-wise copy.

It is however very uncommon to implement those trait manually, and most of the time, you'll just go with `derive`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
```